# Trying to install JPype1 but getting errors: cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

Tags: python, java, visual-c++, pip, jpype

Im trying to install JPype1
but i keep getting this:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for JPype1
Failed to build JPype1
ERROR: Could not build wheels for JPype1, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm running on Python 3.12.0

Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.8.3

and pip 23.3.1

Please help :( i need it for an assignment

I tried using

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

and the outcome was:

```
WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.12.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-23.3.2 setuptools-69.0.2
```

I try downloading JPype1 again and the output was:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting JPype1
  Using cached JPype1-1.4.1.tar.gz (797 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (from JPype1) (23.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: JPype1
  Building wheel for JPype1 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for JPype1 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `jype1` is only supported till `python 3.10` yet.

[https://pypi.org/project/JPype1/#:~:text=JPype%20is%20a%20Python%20module,scientific%20computing%2C%20and%20much%20more](https://pypi.org/project/JPype1/#:%7E:text=JPype%20is%20a%20Python%20module,scientific%20computing%2C%20and%20much%20more).

You need to downgrade your python to `3.10` or less.

[image]

Comment: omg i finally downloaded JPype1 after many errors thank you so much!!!